# HMAC-SHA2-224 Lua implementation not giving correct output

Tags: lua, hmac, sha

I have an issue with an HMAC implementation I am trying to write in Lua. The underlying has function I am testing with is SHA2-224. Look at the code below, assuming a correct SHA2-224 implementation:

```
        local print = print
        local byte = string.byte
        local char = string.char
        local concat = table.concat

        local function toBytes(str)
            local tmp = {}
            for i = 1, string.len(str) do
                tmp[i] = byte(str, i)
            end
            return tmp
        end

        local function toString(bArray)
            local tmp = {}
            for i = 1, #bArray do
                tmp[i] = char(bArray[i])
            end
            tmp = concat(tmp)
            return tmp
        end

        -- ignore hFun for now
        local hash = function(hFun, key, message)

            local hasher = require 'sha224'
            local blockSize = hasher.blockSize()
            local outputSize = hasher.outputSize()

            -- if the length of the key is longer than the block size, we hash it first
            -- to shorten it
            -- if its too large, we pad it with 0s until its as big as the block size
            if #key > blockSize then
                key = hasher.hash(key)
            elseif #key < blockSize then
                key = key .. string.rep("\0", (blockSize - #key))
            end

            local keyBytes = toBytes(key)
            assert(#keyBytes == blockSize)

            local opad = {}
            local ipad = {}

            for i = 1, 64 do
                opad[i] = keyBytes[i] ~ 0x5c
                ipad[i] = keyBytes[i] ~ 0x36
            end

            opad = toString(opad)
            ipad = toString(ipad)

            local inner = hasher.hash(ipad .. message)

            return hasher.hash(opad .. inner)

        end
        return {hash = hash}
    end
```

Testing with a test vector from NIST, this code produces the following output (w/ some debug code that is not included above):

For key: "Jefe", message: "what do ya want for nothing?":

```
OPAD 1: 74 XOR 92 --> 22
IPAD 1: 74 XOR 54 --> 124
OPAD 2: 101 XOR 92 --> 57
IPAD 2: 101 XOR 54 --> 83
OPAD 3: 102 XOR 92 --> 58
IPAD 3: 102 XOR 54 --> 80
OPAD 4: 101 XOR 92 --> 57
IPAD 4: 101 XOR 54 --> 83
OPAD 5: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 5: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 6: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 6: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 7: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 7: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 8: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 8: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 9: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 9: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 10: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 10: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 11: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 11: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 12: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 12: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 13: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 13: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 14: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 14: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 15: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 15: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 16: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 16: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 17: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 17: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 18: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 18: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 19: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 19: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 20: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 20: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 21: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 21: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 22: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 22: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 23: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 23: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 24: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 24: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 25: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 25: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 26: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 26: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 27: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 27: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 28: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 28: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 29: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 29: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 30: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 30: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 31: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 31: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 32: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 32: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 33: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 33: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 34: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 34: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 35: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 35: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 36: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 36: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 37: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 37: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 38: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 38: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 39: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 39: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 40: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 40: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 41: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 41: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 42: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 42: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 43: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 43: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 44: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 44: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 45: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 45: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 46: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 46: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 47: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 47: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 48: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 48: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 49: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 49: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 50: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 50: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 51: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 51: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 52: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 52: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 53: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 53: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 54: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 54: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 55: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 55: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 56: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 56: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 57: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 57: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 58: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 58: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 59: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 59: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 60: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 60: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 61: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 61: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 62: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 62: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 63: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 63: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD 64: 0 XOR 92 --> 92
IPAD 64: 0 XOR 54 --> 54
OPAD: 9:9\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
IPAD: |SPS666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666
INNER HASH:  9:9\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\what do ya want for nothing? ----> 9d7a0c2abbbd5d81645ba9aff01a112bb1d1ec878072e2953110cc71
FINAL HASH INPUT: 9:9\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\9d7a0c2abbbd5d81645ba9aff01a112bb1d1ec878072e2953110cc71
FINAL RESULT: 770df99ad235e32bc5e2aacfbbfdedddeac7628a5882920863e920ee
EXPECTED RESULT: a30e01098bc6dbbf45690f3a7e9e6d0f8bbea2a39e6148008fd05e44
```

I am pretty sure that I am not doing anything wrong when it comes to the padding as well as the creation of the opad and ipad tables. Perhaps my string to int conversions are off. Perhaps its a weird quirk with Lua 5.3 that I don't know about. I don't know what I am missing here. It could be very obvious, but I am not seeing it at the moment. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

I should add that this implementation is needed for a lua sandbox in which I cannot use other libraries.

Comment: I found the issue. The contents of the inner hash are not supposed to be outputted as a hex value. Only the final result should be made a hex value. Once I made the changes to my SHA2-224 implementation to accommodate this, the code worked as expected.